# Unable to trash items.

Tags: google-apps-script

I cannot for the life of me figure this out, the script appears to run, but will not trash the files, every file errors. Either an issue with the script or probably some setting I haven't turned on. I am really stuck, I am owner of all these files and admin of the domain.

```
 function deleteMyBAKs(){
 var ThirtyDaysBeforeNow = new Date().getTime()-3600*1000*24*30 ;// 30 is the number of days
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();
if(file.getName().toLowerCase().match('.bak')=='.bak' && file.getDateCreated().getTime()<ThirtyDaysBeforeNow){
  try{file.setTrashed(true);}
  catch(e){Logger.log("Unable to Trash: "+file.getName()) }         
  Logger.log(file.getName()+' created on'+Utilities.formatDate(file.getDateCreated(), 'GMT','MMM-dd-yyyy'));
 }       
} 
MailApp.sendEmail('email@address.co.uk', 'Script AUTODELETE BAK report',     Logger.getLog());
}
```

Comment: Actually I have noticed that all these are actual shared files owned by another domain, which is really weird. Why out of 1.5 million files does it only choose the shared ones? Are they first on the list? If so is there a way of doing the hasNext function in reverse?

Comment: It actually appears to be deleting .bak files but it doesn't report them only reports the ones that won't delete.

Comment: Instead of sharing your on-going foundings, consider to update your question. Regarding the use of comments, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment. It's worth to say, that if you will doing major changes, will be better to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The setTrashed method only works for files where you are the actual owner. It may not work for shared documents.